# How to locate device on network?

Tags: find, ip, lan

CodeLath, maker of the TonidoPlug walwart, provides a web server to locate the Plug on the LAN:

http://www.tonidoplug.com/ip/

I'm curious to know how a script located on some web servers on the Net manages to find the IP address of a device located on my LAN that uses the non-routable, private address plan 192.168.x.x.

If it fails, the user can enter the MAC address, and the web script will try again to find it.

Does someone have an idea how it's done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the devices "phone home" to TonidoPlug's website with their MAC and IP addresses, and this script just queries the database for a matching device...

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a replica of your SQLEXPRESS/MDF local file- on a remote server (SQL Server 2005), you can right click in the "Server Explorer" on your `db.mdf` file and press "Publish to provider...". You can choose a variety of compatibilities with SQL Server 2005, 2008, etc. The output is a `.sql` query file .